# How do you calculate the end point coordinates for an arc, given the centre coordinates, radius and sweep angle?

Tags: php, geometry

I'm working in PHP with some filled arcs and I'm having trouble finding a way of calculating the coordinates for the end point of an arc. I know the **centre point coordinates**, the **radius** (the width and height are the same), the **start angle**, and the **end angle** (as is required by the php imagefileldarc() function). From this, how can I calculate the end point coordinates for the arc?

I've tried the following formula to no avail:

```
$end['x'] = cos($Angle) * $Radius + $CenterX; 
$end['y'] = sin($Angle) * $Radius + $CenterY;
```

Many thanks

Comment: You are using radians for $Angle, aren't you?

Comment: I'm using degrees for the angle.

Comment: I've just converted the degrees to radians using PHP's `deg2rad()` and it seems to be working now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are drawing an arc does not really matter. Your calculation will always be:

x=cos(angle)*radius + centerx
y=sin(angle)*radius + centery

Comment: Many thanks for your help but this isn't working as expected. I've edited my question to include the changes.

Comment: You don't describe what ratio is supposed to represent in this context.

Comment: @arkon it was a typo... radius is spelled "radio" in Spanish, my mother tongue, so I picked the wrong term. It is fixed now.
Note that person who wrote the question, at some point included my answer in his/her question, but using the correct term.